# Component method fails to assign data that has not yet been fetched by the service

Tags: asp.net, angular, typescript

**officeView.component.ts**

```
setSelectedPerson(id:number)
    {
        this.pservice.getPerson(id);
        localStorage.setItem("selectedPerson", JSON.stringify(this.pservice.person));
    }
```

**person.service.ts**

```
getPerson(id:number)
    {
        this.http.get(personUrl + id).subscribe(response => this.person = response )

    }

person:Person;
```

I'm executing setSelectedPerson method from OfficeViewComponent and here's what I'm hoping to happen:

1. I ask PersonService to fetch the data from api and assign it to it's variable - PersonService.person;
2. Now that the response is assigned to the service person variable, I'm expecting it to be stringified and saved in localStorage.

But here's what actually happens:

I ask PersonService to fetch the data, PersonService reacts and proceeds with the request, but by the time PersonService.getPerson() is finished, localStorage has already attempted to collect the data from PersonService.person, which - at that time - was unassigned.

I know there is a way to wait until the service method finishes it's work, but I don't know exactly what should I use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return the subscription from the service and use it to set data inside it. You don't need any variable inside your service.

**officeView.component.ts** :

```
setSelectedPerson(id:number){
    this.pservice.getPerson(id).subscribe(
        response => {
            localStorage.setItem("selectedPerson", JSON.stringify(response));
        },error => {
            console.log('Error :',error.error)
        }
    )
}
```

**person.service.ts** :

```
getPerson(id:number) : Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get(personUrl + id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're right, you should wait until the result is ready.

By then you can call the setSelectedPerson func.

```
//service func
getPerson(id:number) {
   return this.http.get(personUrl + id);
}

//component func
setSelectedPerson(id:number){
   this.pservice.getPerson(id).subscribe(data => {
       localStorage.setItem("selectedPerson", JSON.stringify(data ));
   });   
}
```

Comment: However, a better approach is to set `localStorage` in the service itself, unless you have an extra logic to include in the component.

Answer (score 0):

person.service.ts

```
getPerson(id:number) {
     return this.http.get(personUrl + id);

person:Person;
```

and when you calling the  HTTP service you should use **subscribe**

```
setSelectedPerson(id:number){
    this.pservice.getPerson(id).subscribe(data=>{
         console.log(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: I can't seem to use subscribe on this.pservice.getPerson(id)

Comment: @kzmijak when you calling any httt method as a service you should use subscribe to  receive the data

Comment: Dude, ensure your logic is correct before posting. You are subscribing the HTTP method inside the service. So what are you subscribing inside component?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with you code is the `early subscribe` in service itself, Ideally it should be in the component (at the caller)

**officeView.component.ts :**

```
setSelectedPerson( id : number ){
    this.pservice.getPerson(id).subscribe(
        response => {
            localStorage.setItem("selectedPerson", JSON.stringify(response));
        },error => {
            console.log( 'Error :',error.error )
        }
    )
}
```

**person.service.ts :**

```
getPerson( id : number ) : Observable< any >{
    return this.http.get( personUrl + id );
}
```